# Remove or ignore duplicate entries in terminal history

Tags: command-line, bash

Is it possible to ignore or remove duplicate entries from the terminal history?  Right now, when I click the up-arrow to go through my previous commands, there are lots of duplicates, or when I use the `history` command, it shows lots of duplicate entries. Does pantheon-terminal have the ability to remove/ignore those duplicate entries?

Comment: That's a feature of bash, not of the terminal. It works the same with all terminals and all distributions. What is the full content of your `.bashrc`? Did you start a new terminal? Where did you add the setting — the default `.bashrc` already contains a setting for `HISTCONTROL`?

Comment: A couple of restarts and the setting finally "took".  I added `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` to the bottom of my _~/.bashrc_ file.  Thanks for your help Gilles.

Comment: @dazzle please post as an answer.

Comment: How is this unclear - he wants to remove duplicates from the bash history. There's even an answer.

Comment: @Tim It's unclear *what the question is*. This question isn't asking how to remove duplicates from the bash history — how to do that is stated in the question. This question could be salvaged by editing it to remove that and keep only the question of how to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command history is a feature of the [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Text_.28CLI.29_shells), which is bash, rather than the terminal emulator Pantheon-Terminal.

The behavior around duplicates in the [bash command history](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Using-History-Interactively) can be configured by setting several [variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) whose name start with `HIST`. In particular, [`HISTCONTROL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-HISTCONTROL) is a list of options to tune the behavior. If the option `ignoredups` is included, duplicates are not added to the history. More usefully in my opinion, if `erasedups` is included, when a duplicate command is issued, the earlier duplicate is removed from the list. Thus `ignoredups` retains the duplicate at its earliest position while `erasedups` retains the duplicate at its latest position.

The place to set this variable is the bash interactive initialization file `.bashrc` in your home directory. Open this file in a text editor. Add a line like

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
```

Multiple options are separated by colons, so for example if you want to ignore lines that begin with spaces you need

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups:ignorespace
```

Save `.bashrc`. The changes will take effect the next time you start bash, i.e. the next time you open a terminal or a new tab. You can also type this command at the bash command line, it will take effect for the shell session in which you type it.

Note that the default `.bashrc` on elementary OS already includes a setting for `HISTCONTROL`. So you'll need to either edit the existing `HISTCONTROL=…` line, or add your own at the end of the file (if you add your setting at the beginning, it'll be overridden).

Answer (score 4):

Answered [in comments](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/367/remove-or-ignore-duplicate-entries-in-pantheon-terminal-history#comment699_367) by OP:

> A couple of restarts and the setting finally "took". I added `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` to the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` file. Thanks for your help Gilles.

Answer (score 0):

To uniqely record every new command is tricky. First you need to add to
`~/.profile` or similar:

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Then you need to add to `~/.bash_logout`:

```
history -a
history -w
```